# What are the considerations of allowing users to change their usernames? [extended]

Tags: design-patterns, features, username

[extended from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852832/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-allowing-users-to-change-their-usernames)

Some applications use usernames and some don't. Some allow changing of usernames and some don't. I would like to know the pros and cons of allowing users to change their usernames and what are the rules that usually goes with it like minimum of 1 month before every change or a maximum of 5 changes.

Below are what I have come up so far.

- facebook - yes
- twitter - yes
- imgur - yes
- reddit - no
- google - yes
- youtube - yes (channels)
- deviantart - no
- instagram - yes
- pinterest - yes
- steam - no

I was hesitant to post my opinions on the matter as I would not like to influence the answers that I might get but since some have given out some downvotes below are my initial thoughts.

**PROS**

- more security on accounts
- people could hide from other people
- safer account management

**CONS**

- users could steal other usernames
- users could get away from misconduct
- users would have a hard time finding each other
- more complex database

What are the things you need to consider to allow your users to change their usernames?
Like If its in the case of a social network, most of them do allow changing. When it comes to e-commerce sites most of them don't.

Comment: Asking for lists of pros and cons is too broad (and likely to be closed). Instead, can you provide a specific context in which you're wondering about changing usernames? (For example a username on a social site could be very different from a username on an ecommerce site.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Example: user's real-life name has changed.

In many systems, a username is based on the user's proper name, e.g. given name initial plus family name "jsmith"; over time, these users may change their names, and wish their system username to change to match.

One particularly sensitive example is if a person divorces, and reverts from their married name to their birth name ‒ in which case, they may strongly wish to remove the married name from their system username.